# Port forwarding from within container

Tags: networking, port-forwarding, iptables, docker

For the past two years I have been using Windscribes port forwarding service to access a few services within my LAN from an external IP. Because I am behind a NAT this has been the best solution and has been working just fine for my use cases. The Windscribe service has been running in a Docker container and has been forwarding ports to other containers on my server.

Recently I have replaced my server and moved everything from the old one. For some reason this broke my forwarding ability and I cannot seam to figure out why. I have been testing this using iperf3 using only the local IP's, just to rule out any issues form Windscribe. I set up two PC's, one running iperf server and the iperf client with the forwarding container in between. If I run the test directly from one PC to the other it works fine. If I use the server host to forward it works fine also. Even iperf server within the container works, just not forwarding from inside the container. I even tried running the container in privileged mode, but nothing.

I am running the same container version, the same config files, the same host OS (Ubuntu 22.04 server) etc. I just moved things to another machine, because the old one broke.

This is iptables output from the container.

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             windscribe   

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination   

**nat

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:5201 to:192.168.36.56

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  tcp  --  anywhere             target               tcp dpt:5201
```

Running iperf from the client PC to the container just gives an error

```
iperf3: error - unable to connect to server: Connection refused
```

Running it directly to the iperf server works fine.

```
Connecting to host 192.168.36.56, port 5201
[  5] local 192.168.36.105 port 48912 connected to 192.168.36.56 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr  Cwnd
[  5]   0.00-1.00   sec   114 MBytes   958 Mbits/sec   26    475 KBytes
```

**EDIT:**
After playing around, I found sort of a solution, but then again not really. I have a specific vlan on my network that I use for containers (LXD and Docker). I created this via netplan and added it to LXD and Docker using the vlan interface as parent. After removing it from netplan and creating the vlan networks directly within Docker and LXD, forwarding works. But this means that I need two interfaces for each of the container types, which I don't consider much of a solution. Strange part is that forwarding is the only thing not working with the netplan setup. The network otherwise works fine. Containers can talk to other devices on the network, which in turn can talk back to the containers, which can also talk to each other (LXD to Docker, Docker to Docker etc). Forwarding within containers is the only thing that breaks.